# UIView will not render

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm initializing a `UIView` to later be captured as an image and used as an `NSTextAttachment`. The initialization is happening in `viewDidLoad`, for a reason that I can't pin-point the view is never rendered. Even though the it's being called on the main thread. When I use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` to capture it, the resulting image is just a blank white image.

If I quick-look on the view in the debugger, it just opens a blank window with the correct bounds, with on error. If I `po` in the console, it outputs the view and the subviews with the correct bounds and text.

Even a very simple example like this:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[view setBackground:[UIColor redColor]];
```

will not render.

I understand that question is incredibly vague, but if anyone can give be some idea on where I should be looking to find the issue, I'd really appreciate it!

Sample usage code

```
CustomView *view = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300)];
view.title = @"View Title";
// ... more view setup

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0f);
[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.frame afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
attachment.image = viewImage;
NSAttributedString *attString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];
self.textView.attributedString = attString;
```

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried invalidating the view so it'll redraw?

Comment: How is the view used? Is it added as a subview anywhere?

Comment: @MattyAyOh that's a good idea, I'll try that.

Comment: @rmaddy no, I take the view and render it as an image and add to an Attributed string.

Comment: It would help a lot of you provide some relevant code.

Comment: @rmaddy added sample code

Comment: @isal did you get it?

Comment: Any luck on this? I have the exact same issue (and approach) - I generate a custom `UIView`, create an `UIImage` from it using `drawViewHierarchyInRect`, add it to a `NSTextAttachment` as an image, and then place it into an `NSAttributedString`, but get blank results. Oddly, if my `NSTextAttachment` image is an image already in the applications bundle (`[UIImage imageNamed:@""]`) it has no issues, so I know my approach is fine, just using `drawViewHierarchyInRect` seems to be a bit buggy?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it as a subview,

`[self.view addSubview:view];`

Comment: I don't use it as a subview. I capture a snapshot and use the image as a NSTextAttachment.

Comment: But on your code you do not render it in some way. Do you want to replace the existing view?

Comment: Added some sample code to show how I'm using it. @Lukas Wiklund

Comment: I still don't see it render somewhere in the code... @isal

Comment: The ```view``` is captured as an ```UIImage```, which is then used as the image attribute for a ```NSTextAttachment``` @Lukas Wiklund